# What kind of key for RYY?

Tags: animation

After creating an object, if I create a rotation key and in the GraphEditor, I only select the F-curve relative to Y, it is as if I had created an F-curve relating to the ransformation RY.

But if I'm interested in RYY processing, what kind of rotation key should I choose?

Comment: I've heard of similar problems that sometimes can be worked around, depending on the specific purpose you're trying to achieve. Could you give some details?